# Taking rows of a matrix given a batch of indices - Python

Tags: python, matrix, rows, jax

How can we extract the rows of a matrix given a batch of indices (in Python)?

```
i = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]
a = jnp.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]])


def extract(A,idx):
    A = A[:,idx]
    return A

B = extract(a,i)
```

I expect to get this result (where the matrices are stacked):

```
B = [[[1,2],
      [2,3]],

      [[2,3],
       [3,4]],

      [3,4],
      [4,5]]]
```

And NOT:

```
  B_ = [[1, 2],
     [2, 3],
     [3, 4]],

     [[2, 3],
     [3 ,4],
     [4, 5]]]
```

In this case, the rows are stacked, but I want to stack the different matrices.

I tried using

> jax.vmap(extract)(a,i),

but this gives me an error since a and i don't have the same dimension.... Is there an alternative, without using loops?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `vmap` if you specify `in_axes` in the right way, and convert your index list into an index array:

```python
vmap(extract, in_axes=(None, 0))(a, jnp.array(i))
# DeviceArray([[[1, 2],
#               [2, 3]],
# 
#              [[2, 3],
#               [3, 4]],
# 
#              [[3, 4],
#               [4, 5]]], dtype=int32)
```

When you say `in_axes=(None, 0)`, it specifies that you want the first argument to be unmapped, and you want the second argument to be mapped along its leading axis.

The reason you need to convert `i` from a list to an array is because JAX will only map over array arguments: if `vmap` encounters a collection like a list, tuple, dict, or a general [pytree](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytrees.html), it attempts to map over each array-like value within the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing right away on the matrix `a` transposed:

```
a.T[i,:]
```